# PL SQL map result set to multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

If we have 3 tables for example A, B and C and a cursor like

```
FOR i IN (
     SELECT * 
       FROM A 
       JOIN B ON(...)
       JOIN C ON(...)
) LOOP
--is there an easy way to map every row to 3 records(A%rowtype, B%rowtype and C%rowtype)?
END LOOP;
```

Comment: By *mapping* you mean?

Comment: @Hawk In the LOOP I have `i` that holds the data from all the tables. But I need a record that holds the data only from table A (A%rowtype) for the current row. Same for B and C.

Comment: Of course I can do it manually `recA.ID := i.A_ID, recA.NAME := i.A_NAME` and so on. But there are a lot of columns, so I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Boneist I want to pass the records as parameters to different functions.

Comment: There is no other efficient way, as far as I know, than to copy the variables manually, like you mentioned in your earlier comment. If all you're concerned about is having to type them out, then I'm sure you could knock up a sql statement that queries user_tab_cols and generates the text for you, eg `select 'reca.'||column_name||' := i.'||column_name||';' from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'A';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that fetching records by ROWID is faster than by index. But you will gain a tiny loss of performance (comparing to simple FOR LOOP) with the following trick, because nothing is free.

```
DECLARE
  l_rec_a table_A%ROWTYPE;
  l_rec_b table_B%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

  FOR i IN (SELECT a.ROWID first
                 , b.ROWID second
                 FROM table_A AS a
                 JOIN table_B AS b on a.id = b.id)
  LOOP
    SELECT * INTO l_rec_a FROM table_A WHERE ROWID = i.first;
    SELECT * INTO l_rec_b FROM table_B WHERE ROWID = i.second;

   /* do something */

  END LOOP;

END;
```